# How to install cmake 3.7 in Ubuntu 16.04 using its binary archive file?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cmake

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed `cmake` with the command

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

It installed `cmake 3.5.1`. Now I want to use `cmake 3.7` - I downloaded an archive with binaries (i.e `cmake-3.7.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz`) and extracted it, but how do I run it using the `cmake` command? My current attempt to run

```
cmake --version
```

returns the "old" `3.5.1` version.

Comment: Which version you downloaded? source or binary?

Comment: @SuB Binary version.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: That problem cause is unavailability of cmake's server, but here is installing an version of cmake that does not exist in Ubuntu Repositoroes.

Comment: @SuB: Let's continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48782).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove old version using:

```
apt-get purge cmake
```

You can use new version of `cmake` by adding its `bin` directory path to `$PATH`. An alternative solution is to extract `tar.gz` package and go to the directory made after extracting and run following commands:

```
cp -r bin /usr/
cp -r doc /usr/share/
cp -r man /usr/share/
cp -r share /usr/
```

The second method is the same as installation process which `.deb` package does!

Comment: With the difference that you can remove a deb package easily. How do you plan to remove this when not needed?

Comment: I agree - how to remove it if we just copied folders?

Comment: @muru: It is drawback of installing a package using this method. Compiling from source code has the same problem in some packages! In this case this package could be removed by deleting any file which is copied. Another solution is to make a `.deb` package and installing it.

Comment: There is a package for cmake 3.7 [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/cmake) in Ubuntu repository for `zesty` version, but i recommend you not using this package. Installing this package need to force `dpkg` to ignore package version check and may cause broken package database.